# Is it grammatically correct to say 'I have not much time?'

Tags: negation

I am well aware of the fact that in order to form a negative sentence in Present Simple one must use an auxiliary (do/does, am/is/are) or a modal verb (can, may etc).

I wonder whether it is possible to say **'I have not much time.'** (I do not mean 'not so much' time here.) and whether such usage is grammatical.

I mean to say, it is absolutely OK to say 'I have NO time', why is it then incorrect to say 'I have NOT MUCH time'?

I would appreciate it if you referred me to some reliable resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have not much time* is grammatical but rather stilted. If contracted, it would sound much more natural and conversational, *I've not much time* or *I haven't much time*.  *I don't have much time* is how most native speakers would express the idea.

Comment: My first thought was that as an AmE speaker you'd have included *I haven't **got** much time* in the list of "more natural" alternatives. But checking BrE/AmE corpuses for [don't have much / haven't got much](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+have+much%2Chaven%27t+got+much&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20have%20much%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20got%20much%3B%2Cc0) I was a bit surprised to find that the ***got*** version is actually more common over my side of the pond (but it's still a minority usage even here).

Comment: They say in the majority of the coursebooks I have dealt with 'have got' is a British variation of 'have', @FumbleFingers Do you mean to say that 'have got' form is rather scarce nowadays?

Comment: How would you explain that 'I haven't much time' is grammatical? Don't we always need an auxiliary to make up a negation? I have  encountered the form above i.e. 'I haven't much time' in a couple of ancient textbooks, but I am not sure I do understand the way it is formed.

Comment: It is grammatical because plenty of competent native speakers say it. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22haven%27t%20much%20time%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en   Where did you find this rule that an auxiliary is *always* needed to form a negation?

Comment: @Yukatan: I'd say "rather scarce" is a massive overstatement. Superficially, my chart suggests ***don't have much*** is 5-6 times more common than ***haven't got much***. But BrE texts are hugely outnumbered by AmE ones, so misclassification will tend to skew that bias towards the AmE position (where it's **20** times more common). And unquestionably, Google Books favours formal written text over speech, so that will also tend to exaggerate the difference. Finally, I'm older than the average, so ***I'd*** still use it even if it were going out of fashion (but I doubt it is, really).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I was focused on the inclusion of ***got*** with my first NGram. But I think [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%27t+much+time%2Cdon%27t+have+much+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20much%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20have%20much%20time%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows how *[We] **don't have** much time* has largely replaced *[We] **haven't** much time* in the past half-century. So even though this doesn't reflect a syntactic "rule", Yukatan is right to assume an auxiliary is at least "preferred".

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, what you are implying is that 'have got' is more formal than have and at the same time it is not typical of up-to-date BrE... Is that right?

Comment: @Yukatan: Bear in mind that Tᴚoɯɐuo and I are native speakers, but we wouldn't necessarily be aware (in advance of checking resources like NGrams) of all usage shifts like this. Statistically speaking, a usage might decline quite significantly without most people actually *noticing* the change (or thinking there was anything unusual about someone still using a supposedly "out of fashion" form). But as regards the "formailty" of ***got*** - you've got that completely reversed. I'm quite sure including *"**got-support**"* would almost always be more informal than most alternative phrasings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Michael Vince in his "New Elementary Language Practice" 3rd edition Macmillan says that 'US English prefers 'have' to 'have got'', so I have always thought that 'have got' is mainly British. While Michael Swan and Catherine Walter in their Oxford English Grammar Course say that 'we often use 'got' with 'have' especially in spoken English, and especially in present.'

Comment: @Yukatan: I think what they're getting at there is that AmE (in particular, AAVE) often discards the auxiliary in ***present tense*** contexts like *I got $5* where Brits would be more likely to say *I **have** got £5* (or just *I have £5*). But only the more extreme dialectal AmE speakers would discard the auxiliary in present tense ***He got $5*** (for Brits and most non-AAVE speakers, that would only normally "reduce" to ***He's** got £5* as a minimum).

Comment: AmE and AAVE are very different dialects.  *He's got five dollars* is very common in AmE.  *He has got five dollars* is rare in some parts of the country but more common in others. I would peg it as a southernism.

Comment: "I've got he's got, she's got,it's got, we've got, they've got" are UBIQUITOUS in AmE. Their uncontracted forms have regional currency.